# Saving plants from cold front

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, fruit-trees, grass, sod

It’s kind of to late but in Texas we got a unusual front that harmed all kinds of native plants and grasses, our lawn and plants were on of them.

I’ve tried some home remedies with natural composites like egg shells and tea bags, banana peels here and there but is there a better way to prune and sped up or some chemicals?

Comment: I have never heard of a “home remedy” that protects from cold (except covers and heat sources). Are we talking about helping the plants to recover?

Comment: Pretty much, the front passed it is over with sorry for the misinformation, covering and such didn’t quiet help, I heard to maybe wet them and then cover them next time, but now it’s either time to have someone pull them out or maybe treat them but should we maybe add a new mix of soil with extra prosperous or something?

Answer (score 1):

Prevention: Cover them, bring them indoors, or add a heat source. Make sure to keep a layer of mulch on the ground.

Aftercare: For affected plants, prune the damaged, diseased, or deformed parts and add compost or fertilizer after last frost.

Comment: If they are brown then which fertilizer should we add after a unexpected snow storm from typical hot native plants?

Comment: If the plants aren't dormant, you can add the fertilizer now. Type of fertilizer depends on the plant if you're using synthetic. If you use worm castings, etc just go for it and don't worry too much.

Answer (score 1):

As the cold front has hit and passed already, all preventative measures are useless, that horse has bolted, figuratively speaking.

Your next step is to assess the damage and work from there. After a frost wave, some plants will look dead (and some will be, frankly), but can recover by regrowing either from the roots or the stem, depending a bit on the plant. Others may look mostly fine, but cellular damage will become obvious later. Unless you plan to redo your landscaping anyway and take this event as a catalyst, I would recommend to wait a bit longer and watch what’s going on over the next few weeks. Remove obviously dead material, from leaves to whole plants as needed. Remember that there are other natural causes that can seemingly destroy vegetation and it bounces back afterwards - think wildfire or animals.

When you see new growth, consider fertilizing. I won’t give you a “one fits all wonder mixture”, as different plants have different requirements and you need to take that into consideration. You can either use a store-bought product or get some compost or well-ripened manure (You hopefully do have a compost heap? That’s where the banana peels and tea leaves should go, not directly on your plants.).

There is no immediate need to fertilize now if your plants were growing well before - you are looking at “smaller” plants with less foliage and a just restarting growing season. That means your plants will process fewer nutrients. At best, an excess would just be washed away, but too much may also lead to very undesirable effects like “burned” roots or too fast growth which may look pretty sooner (if the plants don’t get just lanky), but can also encourage pests like aphids to make themselves at home in the overly soft greenery. When it comes to fertilizing, rather err on the side of less if you are unsure.

If you have to plan for recurring frost events or are dealing with usually dry conditions, mulch can be your first line of defense. It keeps the soil moist and shaded in the summer and protected in the winter.

Comment: I will take everything into consideration.. kind of bummed about it but it had to happen right? Or was there enough blankets to keep them covered during the snow? Who know next year might repeat!

Comment: We can only wait and see. We gardeners can sometimes get a bit overzealous. I remember that spring when I couldn’t wait to plant my tomatoes before the last frost date (which one knows is a gamble) and ended up tenting them with blankets each evening and slipping two candles in lantern underneath as well. Ridiculous week, but worked. If you had lots of snow, that’s better than just frost. Snow is a surprisingly good insulator. Good luck with your plants!

Comment: So yea if they aren’t inside something climate controlled then yea glad we didn’t waste our time even trying to save stuff. Could I have layered my grass with compost before the snow to maybe save it?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that could save some plants from last winters record low temperatures along the TX coast would be to bring them inside. As of the end of July some stuff has come back, some didn't. I am hoping some of a large fig tree made it. 75% was dead, but half of what leafed out has now died. One sego palm of 20 has still not come back. It was so cold for so long that even covering with a plastic tub, blankets, and tarp was not enough for ground orchids , but they came back from roots.  I am just hoping it was a "one of".